# How to automatically sync files between local folder and Dropbox folder?

Tags: games, 19.04, sync, dropbox, symbolic-link

I'm trying to set up a sort of DIY cloud-saves system for a game on Ubuntu so that I could share saves for a game between 2 systems, using Dropbox. The intended result is for the saves to automatically be uploaded to Dropbox whenever I save the game, and for any new saves to automatically be updated on the local machine if the save on Dropbox was newer than the save on the local machine (so basically just if I played the game on the other machine).

Previously, I was able to do this by using a symlink, with the command `sudo ln -s "/folder/containing/saves" ~/Dropbox`, however I've had to redo it and it seems like that no longer works. Before, it would copy the folder onto Dropbox, and then any change made in either folder would be reflected in the other folder. However, now it just seems to create a symlink file, so the actual saves themselves do not get uploaded to Dropbox. Therefore, any changes to the saves can no longer be transferred to the other machine. Anyone have any idea how I could fix this so that the command works like it used to, or if there're any other methods of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just save the file (perhaps to a discrete folder) to your Dropbox folder in your home directory. I do tis for a 3rd party accounts program and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Graham Unfortunately that's not an option, as the game has a hard-coded location for it's saves.

Comment: If you launch the Website, you can select to share an existing folder.

Comment: @Graham I'm not sure I follow. How would that cause my save files to be copied onto Dropbox and back automatically. Surely that would require me to manually upload and download the files each time, which I could do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem *could* be due to Dropbox no longer supporting encrypted filesystems.

You can tell if you have an encrypted `HOME` directory

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ df -m $HOME
Filesystem          1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/home/walt/.Private    316201 141080    159038  48% /home/walt
```

Using my `pathlld` tool ( https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git ) to examine the situation more fully, it shows:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ pathlld $HOME
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov 18 10:06 /
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=32589,data=ordered)
# / is /dev/sda5 and is an ext4 filesystem
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 36864 Sep 10 12:08 /home
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=32748,data=ordered)
# /home is /dev/sda7 is an ext4 filesystem
drwx------ 255 walt walt 282624 Nov 18 12:25 /home/walt
/home/.ecryptfs/walt/.Private on /home/walt type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=1e8eb7b6d86aafbf,ecryptfs_sig=c2ba21b5be0aa03e,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
# /home/.ecryptfs/walt/Private on /home/walt is an
# "ecryptfs" decrypted view of an encrypted filesystem,
# visible (mounted) only while I'm logged in.
```

The solution (works for me on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and 18.04LTS ) is to create the `Dropbox` directory on an `ext4` partition, e.g., `/home`

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l ..
total 304
drwx------   3 walt  walt   4096 Nov  5  2018 Dropbox
drwx------   2 root  root  16384 Jan 29  2018 lost+found
drwx------ 255 walt  walt 282624 Nov 18 12:25 walt
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

I did this:

```
sudo mkdir -m 0700 /home/Dropbox
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/Dropbox
```

Then, I opened "Dropbox Preferences" from the icon in the top row, clicked on the "Sync" tab, and, after specifying the new "Dropbox folder location" (`/home/Dropbox`) clicked on "`Move`".